# R randomForestSRC: how to extract (or calculate) the variance explained?

Tags: r, random-forest

suppose I have an object "database" out of an `rfsrc(..)` (randomForestSRC package) call.
Calling `database` gives me (in my particular case)

```
                         Sample size: 13209
                     Number of trees: 5000
           Forest terminal node size: 5
       Average no. of terminal nodes: 1890.76
No. of variables tried at each split: 20
              Total no. of variables: 58
       Resampling used to grow trees: swor
    Resample size used to grow trees: 8348
                            Analysis: RF-R
                              Family: regr
                      Splitting rule: mse *random*
       Number of random split points: 10
                % variance explained: 40.6
                          Error rate: 43.9
```

I am looking for a command that extracts the exact "% variance explained" into a variable. Something like (fictious) `varEx <- database$variance[1,2]` or `varEx <- rfsrc.explVar(database)`.
Currently a quick and dirty option would be with `capture.output()`, but there must be a proper way I guess.

Any ideas? That would be great!

BTW: the same would also be interesting (though not urgent currently) for "database" being from a `randomForest(..)` (randomForest package) call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the formula in `randomForestSRC::print.rfsrc`!

Since you have "regr" as family, the formula for the % variance explained is:

```
per.var <- round(100 * (1 - err.rate[nrow(err.rate),]/var(x$yvar, na.rm = TRUE)), 2)
```

Hope it helped you.